# Setting layer transparency in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layers, transparency-opacity

I just switched from QGIS 2.18 to version 3.0.3. In the earlier version, setting layer transparency was easily done with the "transparency" slider from the Layer properties->style tab. See image below:

[image: QGIS 2.18 layer properties "style" tab]

The newer QGIS version, however, does not appear to display such a transparency bar, as seen in next image. Is there a simple way to change a layer transparency in this version of QGIS?

[image: QGIS 3.0.3 layer properties "symbology" tab]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to click on the layer rendering arrow (see the bottom of your second image) to access the slider and other option.

in QGIS 2 it was on by default, in QGIS 3 it's off by default...

Comment: Great! Talk about a simple solution!

Comment: @LandryF Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 24):

As an alternative option, you can unfold the `Legend` tab and select `Opacity slider` widget.
It will add an opacity slider in the Layers panel.

[image]

If you don't have an opacity widget yet you can enable it in the Layer Properties:

[image]

Comment: I assumed the opacity slider was only available for rasters until I read your answer. Thanks @Kazuhito!

Comment: In case a future reader wonders how to find the Legend tab, it is accessed in the Layer Properties window (double-click a layer in the Table of Contents).  Thanks @Kazuhito

Comment: For anyone else adding the slider and then not finding it: you need to use the little arrow on the left to drop it into view 