# QGIS shortcut to transparency

Tags: qgis, transparency-opacity

Is there a shortcut key to increase or decrease layer transparency, or to add the opacity slider to a layer in QGIS?

I couldn't find one in the existing shortcut key list and I tried loading the transparency file to that list, but it doesn't like the format.

A while back I noticed there Python script that can do something similar, add transparency to new layers imported into the workspace, but I am looking for a simpler tool.

Comment: It really needed editing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Credits to @Kazuhito from his answer
> https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/284797/99589

Try the **"Opacity slider"** via `RMC > Properties > Legend > Embedded Widgets in Legend > Available widgets`

[image: Opacity slider]

and edit the transparency

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks very much, I was just looking for something a bit quicker. Cheers

Comment: If it solves your problem please accept it

Comment: I've accepted it now, sorry didn't know I needed to, new to this. I am still hanging out for somebody to show me a quicker way e.g. adding a shortcut key.

Answer (score 6):

This is more a workaround but still can be useful:

Transparency/Opacity can be a tailored globally (all layers etc.) or individually by layer.

This way is by layer:

**Layer Styling** [Shortcut] is **F7** in QGIS.

This can be docked in QGIS for quick access.
This then allows the user to pick the slider for any of the layers in the canvas including images/raster's.

This screenshot shows where layer styling is available [or use **F7** on the keyboard to bring it up or remove the panel]
[image]

Windows 10 Pro (QGIS 3.14 used here)

Comment: OK, thank you.Looks like this is the way to go for now.

Comment: I see that v3.16 now has increase and decrease as an option in the keyboard shortcuts, which is very nice. However, I think I can only get it working by first clicking on the opacity slider first, and then it increments by 1%, so it's still a bit slow. I love this program and am just being a pain. I must learn how to create a plug-in.

Comment: @NigelCantwell where do you see this option in the keyboard shortcuts? If it was there it would solve this problem, but it's not...

Comment: I just found it by searching transparency in keyboard shortcuts, and it's really nice to have. It is a solution to the problem, but it only increments by 1%, so still a bit slow.